# Problems writing a REGEX

Tags: regex, replace

I need some help with a regex.
My problem is to extract the version number from a jar/war artefact so I can run an mvn deploy-file of my legacy to nexus
The lines are just like below

```
-DartifactId=my-jarfile-1.2.1 -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=war
```

My task is to make it something like that

```
-DartifactId=my-jarfile -Dversion=1.2.1 -Dpackaging=war
```

I am trying the following but I am not having success:

```
^(?:-DartifactId=.)$(\d+)(\.\d+)(\.\d+)$|^(\d+)(\.\d+)$|^(\d+)$|^(\d+)(\.\d+)(-.+)$|^(\d+)(-.+)$
```

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex that I'd be using, assuming that the switches always appear in that order:

```
/-DartifactId=my-jarfile-([0-9.]+)(.*-Dversion=)<version>/-DartifactId=my-jarfile\2\1/g
```

See it at work here: https://regex101.com/r/2pnp5G

Comment: If the "my-jarfile" bit is supposed to not be fixed, then you should modify this expression a bit, of course. You could just capture ([\w-]+) and include it in the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the just version number:

```
-Dversion=((\d+\.)*\d+)
```